# Is it possible to improve your Cave of Shadows saved data after unlocking the final section?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess-hd

When you complete the first two rounds of the Cave of Shadows, you can save your remaining health and other information to the Wolf Link Amiibo. Scanning the Amiibo while in the Cave of Shadows will restore your health to the level you had when you saved.

I did the second level of the Cave of Shadows when I had 14 Heart Containers, and I saved with 13 hearts of health.

I didn't play the Cave again until after getting the Sol-infused Master Sword and collecting all 20 Heart Containers. I can also regularly get to the 20th floor of the Cave with full health.

But so far as I can tell, there's no way to save my full health to the Amiibo now that I have unlocked the full Cave of Shadows. I did beat the full Cave on my third attempt with six hearts remaining — but it doesn't save anything to the Amiibo when you do.

If I had finished the second Cave section with only seven hearts remaining, I can't imagine that I would ever have been able to complete it. This sort of permanently-missable thing is not typical for a Zelda game. And whatever the Wolf Link Amiibo does with the upcoming Wii U Zelda, I want it to be maxed out.

So: Is there any way for me to improve the data saved to the Amiibo without starting a new save file from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game only saves data to the Amiibo if you've completed the cave, or as much of the cave as you've unlocked, with more hearts remaining than your previous time.

Your Amiibo currently has data with 13 hearts remaining, so you'll only be able to save again if you finish the entire thing with 13.25 or more hearts. If you finish it with all 20 hearts, you won't be able to save into the Amiibo any more.

It's not clear whether this is intended or a bug. On one hand the main use for the data in the Amiibo is to restore your hearts (we don't yet know how Zelda U/NX will use it), so you'd want the most of them you can have. On the other hand it also saves other data (such as which other Amiibos you used) so perhaps it should give you a chance to decide you'd rather save fewer hearts but a better overall "score".

Update as of 2017-01-31:

We now know what the "Zelda U/NX" (titled *Breath of the Wild*) will use the amiibo for: To conjure a wolf to help you, which has as many hearts as are saved in the amiibo. So it makes sense for it to only remember the time you finished with most hearts.

Comment: That's the most half-cocked, poorly thought through design I've ever heard of. Really shoddy work. Thanks for the answer, though!